# Downvotes on SE Meta start showing up in Recent Achievements

Tags: support, voting, meta, stack-exchange

At the risk of asking a silly question, because maybe I just overlooked this all this time:

I am surprised to see a downvote on my SE Meta question pop up in my recent achievements. I don't posts on SE Meta that much, but on SO Meta a bit more, and I don't recall ever seeing reputation changes related to meta posts.

So, what changed, if anything?

[image]

Comment: That's been happening for as long as I've been on meta.

Comment: SE meta is the only Meta page that handles reputation. The individual site metas don't have reputation consequences to posts, so that's why you never see it unless it's SE Meta

Comment: Good thing I asked this here, not there then. ;-)  Thanks, @DavyM

Comment: It seems I have only 6 SE questions, and all from 2010/2011. This seems to be the only one with downvotes, and the previous downvote was from 2016. With 5 rep changes anyway in 4 years time, I think I just never noticed or realized that SE is different from SO meta in this regard.